# Need to get log file in folder in java

Tags: java, logging, error-logging, properties-file, error-log

This is my log4j property file, i need to get log file in this location, but it didn't create

```
# Root logger option
log = D:\\log
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

in my class i initiate like this

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(test.class);
```

& i added info or err when i need ex

```
LOGGER.info("Get Request from Service");
```

I can get this output in console but i didn't get that log file.

Answer (score 2):

Use FileAppender for this purpose

```
 # Root logger option
 log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

 # Direct log messages to a log file
 log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.file.File=D:/log/application.log
 log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
 log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
 log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**read some 
[log4j tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/)**

specify your file location here

```
    log4j.appender.file.File=<location of your file goes here>
ex :log4j.appender.file.File=D:/log/application.log
```

Comment: I can't see the folder creation in this config piece

Comment: log4j.appender.file.File=<your file location>
          
example:log4j.appender.file.File=C:/logs/application.log